# How to disable dark mode on stackoverflow

Tags: discussion

I love to use dark mode. But due to some reason I feel the recent update to the stackoverflow dark mode is not proper.

I want it to disable the darkmode on stackoverflow. However I'm not able to find how to disable the dark mode settings in stackoverflow website.

Thanks,